# Python SQLite database not growing

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to fill in a SQLite database using the Python library `sqlite3`. In this example, the idea is simply to read data from a file and populate the database, however, although it seems the table is being created, the database is not growing and values are not written to it.

The code I have is below:

```
import sqlite3


def update_db(c, key, val):
    sql = ''' UPDATE atable SET f1 = ? WHERE id = ?; '''
    c.execute(sql, (val, key))


def create_table(c):
    sql = ''' CREATE TABLE atable (id text PRIMARY KEY, f1 integer DEFAULT 0); '''
    c.execute(sql)


with sqlite3.connect('test.db') as conn:
    c = conn.cursor()
    create_table(c)

    with open('file1.txt') as f1:
        for line in f1:
            l = line.strip().split()
            update_db(c, l[0], int(l[1]))

    conn.commit()
```

This code runs without errors, but when trying to query this database, either with Python:

```
with sqlite3.connect('test.db') as conn:
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM atable;')
    for row in c:
        print(row)
```

or in the SQLite command interface:

```
$ sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> SELECT * FROM atable;
sqlite> .tables
atable
sqlite>
```

the output is always empty (but it looks the table was correctly create). What am I doing wrong here?

The 'file1.txt' for testing is this:

```
foo 2
bar 0
baz 1
```

Comment: You're trying to UPDATE rows; are you sure you don't mean to INSERT some rows?

Comment: @khelwood, not sure, I'm just learning SQLite now. The idea is to read from several files (that don't fit into memory) that can share (or not) the same key "id", and so the update . For each key "id" (row) the final database is supposed to have multiple columns.

Comment: If all you do is UPDATE, your table will stay empty. UPDATE does not add rows; INSERT does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL syntax for adding rows to your table is:

```sql
INSERT INTO atable (id, f1) VALUES (?, ?);
```

`UPDATE` will do nothing if there are not already rows in the table.

If you want to *insert or replace* an existing row, sqlite also supports an [`INSERT OR REPLACE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) command.

Comment: I see, makes sense. Will this raise any exception or error if the key (row?) already exists?

Comment: Yes, INSERT will raise an exception if the id is already present in the table, since that is the primary key.